# Working Around JavaFX 2.2 Arabic Text Orientation issue

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm using JavaFX 2.2 but everytime I typed arabic text, the order of the chracters are reversed, since the solution to this problem will only be when JavaFX 8 is released. How can I monitor the textbox and automatically reverse the characters typed back to the way it should be with something like:

```
arabicTextBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent t) {

        //TODO: correct arabic text order here
    }
});
```

A sample implementation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Event Filter instead of simple KeyPressed because it will allow you to consume event and override default `TextField` behaviour.

For simplest case (without keyboard navigation) you can handle only `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED`:

```
final TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
        if (KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED == t.getEventType()) {
            // put character to the first position
            tf.setText(t.getCharacter() + tf.getText());
        }
        t.consume(); // doesn't allow TextField to handle keyboard events by itself
    }
});
```

If you want full fledged arabic-only `TextField` you can add logic for arrow keys, caret position, etc.